# JPA (EclipseLink) SecondaryTable erroneous join with java 1.7

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have created an entity joining Customer table with Customer detail table using SecondaryTable annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@SecondaryTable(name="CUST_DETAIL", 
            pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_DETAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUST_DETAIL_ID"))
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUST_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CUST_DETAIL_ID")
    private Long custDetailPk;

    @Column(name = "CUST_DETAIL_ID", table = "CUST_DETAIL")
    private Long custDetailId;

    ...
}
```

It is working with java 1.6, the generated query is like

```
SELECT t0.CUST_ID, t0.CUST_DETAIL_ID, t1.CUST_DETAIL_ID, ... FROM CUSTOMER t0, CUST_DETAIL t1 WHERE t1.CUST_DETAIL_ID = t0.CUST_DETAIL_ID
```

but when I migrate to java 1.7, the generated query seams erroneous

```
SELECT t0.CUST_ID, t1.CUST_DETAIL_ID, t0.CUST_DETAIL_ID, ... FROM CUSTOMER t0, CUST_DETAIL t1 WHERE t1.CUST_DETAIL_ID = t1.CUST_DETAIL_ID
```

and returning multiple rows.

Is there any problem with jpa secondarytable and java 1.7?

Comment: Do you still use the same version of Hibernate?

Comment: You mean, do you still use the same version of EclipseLink ...

Comment: Yes, I am using the same version of EclipseLink. I have tried several new versions with the same result.

Comment: Why do you have the same field (CUST_DETAIL.CUST_DETAIL_ID) mapped twice?  The custDetailId should not be there or annotated as part of the primary key as it is not - the field is set from the custDetailfk value through the SecondaryTable mapping. I don't know why there is a difference in the JVM processing, but I suspect having multiple mappings is getting processed in a different order, so that the extra mapping is being used for the equals check in your queries instead of the one on the main table.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense why both CUST_DETAIL_ID and CUST_ID are IDs for the CUSTOMER when CUST_DETAIL_ID is unique enough to use for the mandatory CUST_DETAIL rows.  Wouldn't just CUST_DETAIL_ID be usable for an ID, or should  CUST_ID == CUST_DETAIL_ID?  If they do not, it seems like the CUST_DETAIL table should treated as its own entity class with a 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution comes from avoiding the confusión caused by the names of the fields CUST_DETAIL_ID, JPA needs to know what table belongs, and the name of the properties custDetail**I**d and custDetail**P**k that it must be ordered alphabetically.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@SecondaryTable(name="CUST_DETAIL", 
            pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_DETAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUST_DETAIL_ID"))
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUST_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CUST_DETAIL_ID", table = "CUSTOMER")
    private Long custDetailId;

    @Column(name = "CUST_DETAIL_ID", table = "CUST_DETAIL")
    private Long custDetailPk;

    ...
}
```